# Access 2016 Table Calculated Field

Tags: ms-access

I have a table containing the following:  Five Y/N fields and a calculated field [Priority Results] that totals the number of 'Yeses' from those five y/n fields. I'm trying to create another calculated field that will return a value of Low, Medium or High dependent on the number of boxes that have been checked. [Priority Results] currently returns the values 0 through -5. Low = 0 & -1, Medium = -2, High = -3 or lower. I've tried SEVERAL different versions of If/Then, If/Else, Iif statements and always receive a syntax error. I've read a lot of different sites and the following expression seems to be the most commonly used, but I'm still getting the error. Anyone have any ideas? I've even tried this statement on a non-calculated field and can't get it to work.

```vb
IIf([Priority results]<="-1","Low",IIf([Priority results]="-2","Medium",IIf([Priority results]>="-3","High")))
```

Here are the calculated field [Priority results] properties.

Expression:

```vb
[Class Non-Attendance]+[Instructor Referral]+[Late Registration]+[Low Starting GPA]+[Talon Log-in]
```

Result Type: Long Integer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxAXn.png)

The part of the table this question relates to has the following fields:

- Class Non-Attendance: Yes/No
- Instructor Referral: Yes/No
- Late Registration: Yes/No
- Low Starting GPA: Yes/No
- Talon Log-In: Yes/No
- Priority Results: Calculated field counting the Yes/No fields above
- Priority Outcome: Calculated field (that isn't working) prioritizing based on Priority Results

Comment: Mandatory link: [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: In addition to @HansUp comment, zero is not less than -1 so it is not captured in the <=-1 condition. Why use negative numbers?

Comment: @HansUp, the field it is looking at is a calculated field. I've tried creating a static field that had 1, 2, 3, and 4 just to see if it had something to do with the field I was using and that didn't work either.

Comment: Andre- This table feeds in to a LOT of queries. There could be numbers add in the future and I was trying to save myself the pain of having to update so many queries...especially if someone else has to do it. We don't have any other Access savvy people in the office and I need to be able to make decent directions in case I win the lottery. :)

Comment: HansUp, It doesn't procude an error. All that happens is that every field is set to high, regardless of how many boxes have been checked.

Comment: I tested again. Still works. Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put parameters for number fields in quotes.

Consider:
`IIf(Abs([Priority Results])<=1, "Low", IIf(Abs([Priority Results])=2, "Medium", "High"))`

In a query or textbox, expression could be:
`Switch(Abs([Priority Results])<=1, "Low", Abs([Priority Results])=2, "Medium", True, "High")`

Comment: This sets everything to high. I had previously tried without quotes/with quotes, everything set to just = (no less than/greater than),,,so many combinations! I hadn't done added Abs, but the equation still doesn't work.

Comment: Expressions work for me. Edit question to provide requested info. Also, show sample data as text table.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the question still confuse me, which is why this answer will be brief.  You have a calculated field PriorityOutcome based on another calculated field PriorityResults and that is the problem.  Access doesn't calculate PriorityResults before calculating PriorityOutcome.  Instead Access says PriorityResults doesn't exist yet and passes null to PriorityOutcome resulting in either an error or a silent fail.
There are several fixes you can mix and match.  You can repeat the calculation for PriorityResults inside PriorityOutcome: wasteful but often the fastest solution.  You can also add a code module with public functions to do part or all of the calculations.  Then refer to those public functions in your calculated fields  Access intellisense can find public functions.

Comment: Mazoula, I have even tried the calculated field on a static text field as well. I created a separate column and manually typed in results myself to test if it was due to the calculated field (Priority Results) or if it was something to do with the expression itself.

Comment: @mazoula, I tested with both calculated fields in table and it works for me.

Comment: sorry I assumed Kmurphy was creating PriorityOutcome in a query.  The second possibility is PriorityOutcome is not set to short text.  If PriorityOutcome is set to short text in the design tab then here is a working calculated field:  IIf([Priority Results]<=-3,'High',IIf([Priority Results]=-2,'Med','Low'))